# Php session fixation example and fixes

Tags: php, security, session

My question is about this summary on session fixation:

- Alice has an account at the bank http://unsafe.com/. Unfortunately, Alice
  is not very security savvy.
- Mallory is out to get Alice's money from the bank.
- Alice has a reasonable level of trust in Mallory, and will visit
  links Mallory sends her.

  1. Mallory has determined that http://unsafe.com/ accepts any session
     identifier, accepts session identifiers from query strings and has
     no security validation. http://unsafe.com/ is thus not secure.
  2. Mallory sends Alice an e-mail: "Hey, check this out, there is a cool new
     account summary feature on our
     bank,http://unsafe.com/?SID=I_WILL_KNOW_THE_SID". Mallory is trying to
     fixate the SID to I_WILL_KNOW_THE_SID.
  3. Alice is interested and
     visits http://unsafe.com/?SID=I_WILL_KNOW_THE_SID. The usual log-on
     screen pops up, and Alice logs on.
  4. Mallory visits http://unsafe.com/?SID=I_WILL_KNOW_THE_SID and now has unlimited access
     to Alice's account. (credit: RichieHindle)

Questions:

Q1 - Is there a way to explicitly prevent the site from accepting any
   session identifier?

Q2 - I don't use the $_GET variable on my site so is there a way to prevent accepting session identifiers from query strings?

- Notes: I'm using php 5.4.3 with SSL and will also use session_regenerate_id..

Comment: Worth a read http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the options martinstoeckli mentioned in his answer, but this won't prevent session fixation. It makes session fixation a little harder to attack, but it doesn't prevent it.

As ServerBloke mentioned, you prevent session fixation by using session_regenerate_id() immediately after verifying the user's login information and before you show the first page that requires authentication.

Making it harder for the attacker to exploit session fixation does not prevent session fixation. You must generate a new session ID.

More and more, people are using public unsecured untrusted wi-fi hot spots. Sessions can be sniffed from the air. On a physical network, they can be sniffed off the wire. They can also force you to visit any URL by employing a man-in-the-middle attack. So, session fixation is still a problem, even if the attacker can't send you URLs.

Knowing that sessions (and passwords) can be sniffed, there is another step that is required to prevent session hijacking. That is HTTPS (TLS/SSL).

All protected pages that require authentication should be accessed only over HTTPS. So, the login page (the one where the user sends their username and password) should be accessed via HTTPs. In that same script, you must regenerate a new sessionID. All pages for the remainder of the session must then be accessed via HTTPs to protect the new session ID.

Here's an example pseudocode login.php script:

```
// Force SSL
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on") {
  die('Must login via HTTPS');
}

// Load the current sessionID
session_start();

// Validate the login information, being sure to escape the input
...
if (! $valid) {
  die('Invalid login');
}

// Start the new session ID to prevent session fixation
session_regenerate_id();

// Clear the old session
$_SESSION=array();

// Log them in
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userID;
```

Comment: Ok. so my ENTIRE site is https/SSL. A user goes to the homepage and the homepage has a login form. at the top of that page I should do session start() and session_regenerate_id? If I'm using SSL then why do I need to regenerate the id? Isn't that just going to negatively impact performance? Also: if I should still use session_regenerate_id even though I have full SSL, then do I need to do it on subsequent pages and also on a timer (every 30 minutes or so?

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say your entire site is HTTPS/SSL, unless you're forcing SSL by detecting it as above, and redirecting. You'll regenerate the session on the page (PHP script) that processes the login submission, not the home page. It won't affect performance to regenerate the session id one time immediately after you verify the user's credentials. Regenerating the session is still important to prevent session fixation, even with SSL, because there are other ways to exploit session fixation (via a shared computer, etc.).

Comment: @Hoxton, to make a long story short, why not prevent session fixation rather than fight against each way to exploit it?

Comment: 1. I have a .htaccess file that redirects every http page to https so every single page uses SSL encryption.

2. So if the user logs in using valid credentials then I do session start() & Session_regenerate_id or do I first do session start, then they login, then I do session_regenerate_id? Also: I've read I should do it on a timeout too (after 30 minutes). 
3. Yes, prevention is better than cure. So by that you mean just use session_regenerate_id or did you have another prevention method in mind?

Comment: @Hoxton., yes, by prevention I mean session_regenerate_id. You need session_start() before session_regenrate_id() because it regenerates the id for the current session and you don't have a session without first doing session_start(). Take a look at first [user provided example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php#107323) for session_regenerate_id(). The .htaccess method should be fine. You will set the login (for example `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userID`) after session_start(), session_regenerate_id(), and clearing the session.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) everytime a user logs in you will prevent session fixation. As the user logs in, their fixated session ID will be regenerated and thus stopping the attack.

Comment: Yeah but I'm still a bit confused about this.
Heres's usage for this from [link]http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html[/link] but it's very confusing, can anyone clarify? 
[code]
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['initiated']))
{ session_regenerate_id(); $_SESSION['initiated'] = true;}
[/code]

"The problem with such a simplistic defense is that an attacker can simply initialize a session for a particular session identifier, and then use that identifier to launch the attack."

Comment: You don't need an `initiated` variable. All you need to do is regenerate the session ID when a user successfully logs in.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1) If your application needs a session, you will **have to** send some kind of session id. If your application doesn't use sessions, then there is no need to call `session_start()`, and ids (whether sent by URL or cookie) are simply not used.

Question 2) You can configure PHP, to accept session ids exclusively from cookies, and to ignore ids from the URL (see [session.use_only_cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies)). If you do that, you should also check, that the option [session.use_trans_sid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) is set to 0 (this is the default).

Comment: Thanks. 
RE: Answer 1: My application does need a session so I think your answer 2 covers the solution.
RE: answer 2: session:use_only_cookies : if this just ignores ids from the url, then it sounds too good to be true,  Are there any side effects? Also: if the default value of session.use_trans_sid = 0, do I need to explicitly set it to 0 just to make sure?

Comment: @Hoxton - It _is_ the recommended way, the only drawback is, that ids in the URL are ignored... This is an advantage in the view of security, but of course it blocks users/systems from using your site, which cannot use cookies (a rare case today). If your site already has use_trans_sid set to 0, there is no need to set it again.

Comment: Ahh you meant in the php.ini file.. These are the settings for my site:
session.use_cookies On
session.use_only_cookies On
session.use_trans_sid 0

Does that mean I'm covered against the fixation attack listed above?
As previously mentioned I'll also be regenerating the id but I'm unsure which solution is best: 
1. Start the session first (without SSL), then let the user login (using SSL) and regenerate the session id or:
2. user logs in (using SSL) and session_regenerate_id is used later if they try to make changes to their profile, etc.

Comment: @Hoxton - I read your comment again, i only meant that you should **check** that use_trans_sid is set to 0. You can do this, writing a php file calling the function `phpinfo()` and running it on the server.

Comment: @Hoxton - If you are really that interested in how to secure your session, i would recommend to read this article [Secure session cookie with SSL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_nomim_cookie). It will make session fixation useless (even when successful), because it separates authentication and maintaining the session.

Comment: I read all the info at your link and am not sure I agree with: "Using the session-cookie only to maintain the session, and not for authentication, is a good thing to do, even when the whole site runs with HTTPS only." because, from php.net: "Prediction refers to guessing a valid session identifier. With PHP's native session mechanism, the session identifier is extremely random, and this is unlikely to be the weakest point in your implementation." and since the entire site is SSL, wouldn't the effect of 2 cookies instead of 1 only impact performance negatively?

Comment: @Hoxton - The randomness of the session-id is indeed not the problem here, because nobody tries to truly _guess_ the id. There are a lot of different approaches to hijack the session id, session-fixation is only one of them. Some are based on unsafe configurations, like the `use_trans_sid` when PHP itself would put the id into the URL, and it is difficult to know all the possible weaknesses. All have in common, that you get the privileges, if you get the session-id. It's only logical that attackers target the session-id, but with the second cookie you can prevent even future threats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand, is this a really problem?

Q1. I think you need to check is there are a SID recieved from GET of COOKIE in you Session storage already (for example, in database). If YES - its'okay, if no, create a new one on server side and do http redirect with new SID.

Q2. I don't use a php 5.4 but i think the following code will help:

```
unset($_GET['sid'])
```

Update: I think the common fix is than only the backend-server can generate a SID identifiers. No user posibilites for this!

Comment: 1. Yes, session fixation attacks really are a problem.

2. I'm not sure your code example would work because as mentioned above, I don't use the $_GET variable on my site.

3. The common fix that you mention. Do you mean the solution listed in the other answers to this question?